# Rails, populating a variable based on the environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanna populate a variable based on the environment it is used. For example the `username` must be test in the `development` environment while something else in the `production` environment.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: test upon `Rails.env.development?` and `Rails.env.production?`

Comment: @apneadiving, these are static config content, is it possible to have it in the config files and use it based on environment type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to store app specific configuration in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110078/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-app-specific-configuration-in-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I understand your problem, you should simply create a yml file.

See [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file).

Answer (score 0):

Look at these options.

1. YAML Configuration. Also related video ([Railscasts Video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file))
2. Configatron  ([Github configatron](https://github.com/markbates/configatron))

Also [related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110078/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-app-specific-configuration-in-rails)